# Editing a List From Inside a For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a list, `mylist`, and I define it to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. How is there a simple way to double every element of the list from within a `for` loop?

I know you could do something like:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] *= 2
```

I also know that you could make a list comprehension:

`mylist = [2*i for i in range(1, 6)`

But is there a way to do it like this?

```
for num in mylist:
   #code goes here
```

I tried doing something like:

```
for num in mylist:
    num *= 2
```

but `num` is a local variable, so this doesn't modify `mylist`, just `num`. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: You could just do `mylist[:] = [2*i for i in mylist]`... as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to do this is with a list comprehension, iterating directly over the list items, not indirectly via an index.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mylist = [2 * num for num in mylist]
print(mylist)
```

**output**

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

That replaces `mylist` with a new list object. That's generally ok, but sometimes you want to modify the existing object, eg when other objects have a reference to `mylist`. You can do that with a slice assignment.

```
mylist[:] = [2 * num for num in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible since you shouldn't try to change a list while looping through it in that way. I would stick with your other two ways of manipulating the list

Comment: It's ok to mutate  a list you're iterating over, as long as you don't add or remove items. But even then, it's _possible_ to alter the number of items in the list if you're careful not to upset the indices of the items you haven't visited yet. Thus you can safely remove items from a list if you iterate over it in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Using an explicit `for` loop.  Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) while iterating and assign a new value to each item.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i, n in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = n * 2
```

Just be careful - don't change the number of items in a list: [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/2823755)